# problem with creating stored procedure and view in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have following stored procedure code when i execute it gives an error saying invalid column name Lat , Lng .These Lat and Lng variables are parameters called from c# code behind with sql query indicated at last in this particular paragraph.

```
CREATE FUNCTION spherical_distance(@a float, @b float, @c float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/@b) ) * COS(  (Lat/@b)  ) * COS( ( Lng/@b ) - (@c/@b) )  + SIN( @a/@b ) * SIN(  Lat/@b  ) ) )    
END

create view [dbo].[business] as 
SELECT Id,
       Name1,
       ZipCode,
       StreetName,
       StreetNumber,
       State1,
       Lat,
       Lng,
       Keyword
  FROM Business_Details

sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select *, spherical_distance( Lat, 57.2958, Lng) as distance
                                     from business 
                                    where (( distance < '" + radius + "' )
                                      and (StreetName like '%" + streetname + "%')
                                      and (Keyword like '%" + keyword1 + "%' )) 
                                 order by spherical_distance(Lat,57.2958,Lng)";
```

Comment: Your query is subject to Sql Injection. (When the streetname variable has the value of " ')); DELETE Business_Details; -- ", running the SelectCommand will empty your table in the database.)

Comment: This question has been repeated as http://stackoverflow.com/q/3615364/217751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting @ sign in front of these parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply i tried by putting @ in front Lat and Lng but it indicates error saying
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spherical_distance, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@Lat".
CREATE FUNCTION spherical_distance(@a float, @b float, @c float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/@b) ) * COS(  (@Lat/@b)  ) * COS( ( @Lng/@b ) - (@c/@b) )  + SIN( @a/@b ) * SIN(  @Lat/@b  ) ) )    
END

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating the `spherical_distance` function, it does not know anything about the `Lat` and `Lng` expressions. Should these be two additional parameters of the function, like `@a`, `@b` and `@c` were? (The function does not know anything about the view.)

Later when you call the function, you pass the value from colum `Lat` into `@a`, and from `Lng` into `@c`, so in the function these two parameters will contain the values from these columns.